# css is not working after uploading the file on server with filezilla

Tags: yii2

css is not working after uploading the file on server with `filezilla` i added `file permission 755` on server and even after that it's not working.

I have changed  `/web/assets/d01711d6/css/bootstrap.css.`

`css` is not working after uploading the file on server with filezilla i added `file permission 755` on server after that it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may depend on several factors.

### **Cache**

If the application is hosted it may be that it is a problem of the server cache so the new CSS file is read to the cache expiration (sometimes several days). In some cases the provider it provides configurations for enabling a temporary mode that disables this mode and promptly update the files.

### Asset Management

Another factor is related to the fact that the directory where content assets are dynamically generated so not always the name of the directory in the development environment and the production server match. It is in these cases to find (looking for it) the actual directory used by the server and replace the file in the right place.

If, as the practice, changes to css file was made in the original directory and not on the copy of the file created by dynamically from asset management, one usually proceeds by eliminating the directory containing the assets of interest and the first subsequent invocation of the application (the URL / link) a new directory of assets is created for these files